# Mapping a function f[xi_,xj_] over a list {x1, ...., xn} with the i < j restriction

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I am often facing the situation where I have a list $\{...x_k...\}$ and where I want to compute:

$$
\{...f[x_i,x_j]...\}\text{ with }\ i<j
$$

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find an elegant solution for this problem. What I'm doing right now seems horrible to me (indirections etc...):

```
n = 4;
x = Table[RandomReal[], n]
```

> {0.547984, 0.601967, 0.000917483, 0.738287}

```
Map[f[Apply[Sequence, x[[#]]]] &, 
    Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n}, {j, i + 1, n}], 1]]
```

> {f[0.547984, 0.601967], f[0.547984, 0.000917483],   f[0.547984,
>   0.738287], f[0.601967, 0.000917483],   f[0.601967, 0.738287], f[0.000917483, 0.738287]}

(in real situation `f` is defined `f[xi_,xj_]:= xi-xj` for instance)

**Question:** what is a better (builtin?) solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Subsets[f @@ x, {2}]
```

> {f[0.817389, 0.11142], f[0.817389, 0.789526], f[0.817389, 0.187803], 
>    f[0.11142, 0.789526], f[0.11142, 0.187803], f[0.789526, 0.187803]}

You can also use

```
f @@@ Subsets[x, {2}]
Join @@ Table[f @@ x[[{i, j}]], {i, 1, n}, {j, i + 1, n}]
```